# Toggle simulated key-press (by two different keys)

Tags: autoit

- I need to make it so that I can press `HotKeySet("{F10}", "stopctrl")` (when I press <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>LCTRL</kbd> should stop getting sent).
- When I press <kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>LCTRL</kbd> should be sent.
- If I press <kbd>ESC</kbd> the program should exit.

Is there any way I can add both functions at once?

```
HotKeySet("{F9}", "startctrl")

Func startctrl()
    Send("{LCTRL down}")
EndFunc

HotKeySet("{ESC}", "Terminate") 

Func Terminate()
    Exit
EndFunc
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44162202/pause-a-while-1-loop-by-using-hotkeyset-in-autoit-script/44170482#44170482).

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ESC</kbd> is a special key, dont use it.

<kbd>F9</kbd> to start and stop the pushing of the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>

<kbd>F10</kbd> to stop the Programm

```
HotKeySet("{F9}", "_startandstop")
HotKeySet("^{F9}", "_startandstop")
HotKeySet("{F10}", "_exit")
HotKeySet("^{F10}", "_exit")

$isdown = False;

while 1
    Sleep(500)
WEnd

Func _startandstop()
    if ($isdown) Then
        ConsoleWrite("up ausgeführt")
        Send("{CTRLUP}")
        $isdown = False
    Else
        ConsoleWrite("down ausgeführt")
        Send("{CTRLDOWN}")
        $isdown = True
    EndIf
EndFunc

Func _exit()
    If ($isdown) Then
        Send("{CTRLUP}")
    EndIf
    ConsoleWrite("exit ausgeführt")
    Exit 1
EndFunc
```

Lg Teifun2

Comment: Read the description carefully. The code does exactly what it's intended to do. It doesn't completely match your reuirements, but you should be able to adopt this to your needs once you understood what is going on there, right? ;-)

Answer (score -1):

```
HotKeySet("{F9}", "startctrl")
HotKeySet("^{F10}", "stopctrl")

HotKeySet("^{ESC}", "Terminate") 
HotKeySet("{ESC}", "Terminate") 

Func startctrl()
    Send("{LCTRL down}")
EndFunc

Func stopctrl()
    Send("{LCTRL up}")
EndFunc

Func Terminate()
    stopctrl()
    Exit
EndFunc
```

Comment: no sir... its now working... F10 Key is not working... 

Func stopctrl()
    Send("{LCTRL up}")
EndFunc

its not working... when i press F10 it should get stop LCTRL function... i think that... it should get work with FLAG